# negative energy cancelling energy

Tags: energy, energy-conservation

In what circumstances can negative energy cancel out energy? If a positron and electron are created they cancel out as one of them has negative energy.
Are there any other ways that negative energy and energy cancel out? Is negative energy everywhere around us or somewhere else?

Comment: Negative energy of the antiparticle is an artifact of relativistic quantum mechanics. It is disappeared in QFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are picturing negative energy as something mystical.

It is important to note thag kintetic energy is positive, while gravitational potential energy is negative.

In case of positron and electron, after creation their kintetic energies are the positive energy, while the potential energy of their system is negative (as one is positive and one is negative in charge)

The above examples of negative energy are of gravitational and electromagnetic potential energies, since these force havd infinite range,  definitely we are always surrounded by negative energy. We are also surrounded by positive energy of motion of gaseous particles and positive electromagnetic potential energy etc.

Comment: Thanks i guess i just needed clarification on what negative energy is

Comment: If an answer solves your probpem then you should accept it as correct,  just saying !